# Average function with collection using Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I need to calculate an average value with Meteor.js using multiple values inside a collection.

In particular, i need to do calculate two things:

1. The difference between the last and the first *obj.km*
2. The sum of all the *obj.liters*

Using javascript I would have written something like this:

```js
var arr = [{
      'km': 12000,
      'liters': 20
   }, {
      'km': 12140,
      'liters': 50
   }, {
      'km': 12240,
      'liters': 45
   }];

function calculate_avg() {
   
   var sum_liters = 0,
       arrlength = arr.length;
   
   for(i = 0; i < arrlength; i++) {
      sum_liters += arr[i].liters;
   }

   return ((arr[arrlength-1].km - arr[0].km)/sum_liters);
};
```

In meteor I am defining a collection named "Refills":

```js
Refills = new Meteor.collection('refills');

// and I insert some example data like in the javascript array
Refills.insert({
   'km': 12000,
    'liters': 20
});

Refills.insert({
   'km': 12500,
    'liters': 15
});

Refills.insert({
   'km': 13000,
    'liters': 35
});

//etc.
```

What is the best way to do that?

I tried to do something like this:

```js
Template.refills.helpers({
  
    avg: function(){
        var sum_liters = 0,
            diff_km = 0;

        Refills.find().map(function (doc, index, cursor) {
                
                //?? var diff_km = doc[last].km - doc[0].km
                var sum_liters += doc.liters;
            
                return ((/*diff_km*/)/sum_liters);
            
        });
        
    }

});
```

Thank you in advance to anybody who will help.

Comment: Doing a `.find().fetch()` will return an array instead of a cursor. You can then run your computations in javascript just like you did before. If your collection is large then you might want to use [mongodb aggregations](http://joshowens.me/using-mongodb-aggregations-to-power-a-meteor-js-publication/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Template.refills.helpers({
  avg: function() {
    // sort refills by km so the math in the last step makes sense
    var refills = Refills.find({}, {sort: {km: 1}}).fetch();
    // use a simple reduce to compute the sum
    var totalLiters = _.reduce(refills, (function(s, r) {return s + r.liters;}), 0);
    // return the average (total distance) / (total liters)
    return (_.last(refills).km - _.first(refills).km) / totalLiters;
  }
});
```

You need to use [fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) on the cursor so you can manipulate an array.